# Input Text Field Label Animation | Vanilla JavaScript

Tags: javascript, css

I am working on Form (Frontend challenge) and stuck with input text field animation.

I have tried to use a placeholder instead of the label but It did not work. I am not sure am I on the right track or not. Sharing the code below. I have to complete it just with Vanilla JS.

When I focus on the input field label goes up as I wanted and the focus out comes back.
But if I fill the input with text, label, and text coming together in the input field. If Input has a text label needs to stay at the top. Thank you in advance.

```js
// console.log("Hey, It's working");
const form = () => {
  const inputText = document.querySelector("input[type=text]");
  const nameText = document.getElementById("yourname");

  inputText.addEventListener("focusin", (e) => {
    nameText.classList.add("active");
  });

  inputText.addEventListener("focusout", (e) => { 
      nameText.classList.remove("active");
  });
};

form();
```

```css
fieldset {
  border: medium none !important;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  min-width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  width: 100%;
}

#sign-up-form {
  padding: 25px;
  margin: 50px 0;
}

input[type="text"] {
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  padding: 10px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}

label {
  font-size: 0.9em;
  opacity: 0.5;
  -webkit-transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out, font-size 0.2s ease-in-out;
  transition: top 0.2s ease-in-out, font-size 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#sign-up-form {
  text-align: center;
}

input {
  margin: auto;
}

fieldset {
  position: relative;
}

label {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  margin-left: -200px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  padding: 0 10px;
}

input {
  display: block;
}

.active {
  top: -20px;
  opacity: 1;
  background-color: $input-background;
  z-index: 1000;
}
```

```html
<form id="sign-up-form">
    <fieldset>
      <label id="yourname" for="yourName">Your Name</label>
      <input
        class="form-control"
        type="text"
        size="30"
        autocomplete="off"
        tabindex="0"
        required
      />
    </fieldset>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2):

Before removing `active` class from `nameText`, you need to check whether the input is empty or not. If the input is empty, there is no need to remove `active` class from `nameText`. See below code snippet.

```
inputText.addEventListener("focusout", (e) => { 
      if(inputText.value.length == 0)
          nameText.classList.remove("active");
});
```

Additionally, [String.prototype.trim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/trim) should also be used to check for whitespaces in `inputText`.

Comment: I see now. I was doing if(inputText.innerText.length == 0) instead. Make sense now. Thanks a lot!